# Prove the function f is zero function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity

Let f : [a, b] → R be continuous. Assume that there exist constants α and β
such that ∀c ∈ [a, b], we have α$\int_a^c$f(x) dx + β$\int_c^b$f(x) dx = 0.
Show that f = 0.

I guess there is a mistake in the question since if α and β = 0 , then the condition is satisfied but the fuction need not be zero function. If α $\ne$ 0 and β $\ne$0, I think f = 0. But I can't prove it. Please give a hint

Comment: Some substitutions to simplify the question: First, what if $c=b$? Next, set $\beta=\alpha+\gamma$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ shouldn't both be $0$

Comment: But we cant take α =1 and β = 0 since they are already fixed.  @nicomezi

Comment: Sorry, I have missread this part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $F(x):=\alpha\int_a^xf(t)dt+\beta \int_x^bf(t)dt.$ By the fundamental theorem, $F$ is differentiable and

$$F'(x)=\alpha f(x)- \beta f(x)$$

for all $x \in [a,b].$ Since $F=0$, we get $F'=0$ , thus

$$\alpha f(x)= \beta f(x)$$

for all $x \in [a,b].$

If $ \alpha \ne \beta$, then $f=0.$

Answer (score 4):

You need $\alpha\neq\beta$. Taking the derivative w.r.t.$c$ you have
$$
[\alpha -\beta]f(c)=0
$$
for every $c$ hence $f\equiv 0$ in $[a,b]$.